# What is the reason for making a nested class static in HashMap or LinkedList?

Tags: java, linked-list, hashmap, nested-class

In most of the cases I've seen that nested classes are `static`.

Lets take an example of `Entry` class in `HashMap`

```
static class Entry<K,V> implements Map.Entry<K,V> {
    final K key;
    V value;
    Entry<K,V> next;
    final int hash;

    .....
    .....
}
```

Or `Entry` class of `LinkedList`

```
private static class Entry<E> {
    E element;
    Entry<E> next;
    Entry<E> previous;

    .....
    .....
}
```

What I know so far about nested class is:

```
- A non-static nested class has full access to the members of the class 
  within which it is nested.

- A static nested class cannot invoke non-static methods or access non-
  static fields
```

My question is, what is the reason for making a nested class static in HashMap or LinkedList?

**Update 1:**

```
Following the already answer link I got an answer - Since And since it does not need 
access to LinkedList's members, it makes sense for it to be static - it's a much 
cleaner approach.

Also as @Kayaman pointed out: A nested static class doesn't require an instance of 
the enclosing class. This means that you can create a HashMap.Entry by itself, 
without having to create a HashMap first (which you might not need at all).
```

I think both these points answered my question. Thanks all for your input.

Comment: Oh! I didn't realized it's duplicate while I was searching for an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A nested static class doesn't require an instance of the enclosing class. This means that you can create a `HashMap.Entry` by itself, without having to create a `HashMap` first (which you might not need at all).

Comment: So, is it always a good practice to make nested class static (and may be private)?

Comment: @Kartic - Nope. Not *always*. I usually steer clear of *nested classes* unless they are *really required*. Nested classes are used based on *design decisions*. `Entry` is a *nested class* because other classes like `Arrays` also have their own *definitions* of `Entry`. *Static nested classes* are usually used for (packaging concerns) making your code *more readable*

Answer (score 1):

1) Because it is not needed from the "outside": it is only used by the enclosing class. By making it a `private` inner static class, this intention is obvious.

2) By being an inner class, it automatically has access to all `private` fields of the enclosing class, so there is no need to create getters or worse like making them package private or `protected`.

#### And why make it `static`?

Non-static inner classes need a reference to an instance of the enclosing class. If the inner class is `static`, this is not needed: instances of `static` inner classes don't have a reference to the enclosing class. They can be created without an instance of the enclosing type and they can live without it.

In case of non-static inner class, the instance of the enclosing class is sometimes transparent (e.g. when you instantiate the non-static inner class from a non-static method of the enclosing class, it is `this`), or can be explicit, e.g.:

```
EnclosingClass ec = new EnclosingClass();
InnerClass ic = ec.new InnerClass();
```

Comment: The question seems to be asking "why make them static", not "why make them private"

Comment: The question says, why are we making it static, no where in your answer are you addressing this point

Comment: @khelwood Sorry, forgot about that. Edited the question to include that.